# Angular2. How can I check if an observable is completed?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

In my page there is a button that generates a report. That report needs data that is loaded using a http call to a rest endpoint when the page is loaded, but I do not have a guarantee that they are loaded when the user presses the report button.

How can I watch the observable to see if it is completed, and if incomplete, to wait on the action until the http call is completed? Here is some of the code:

```js
loadCompanies(): void {
    this._companyService.getCompanies().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.companiesModel = response;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

```
generateReport() {
   // check if observable that loads companies is completed and do the 
   // action using companiesModel.
}
```

One option is a flag set in loading companies with values of 'loading' and 'completed', and make a wait in `generateReport()` until the flag is completed,
but I would prefer a solution using the `Observable` API if possible.

Comment: just do a if(companiesModel) that will do the trick i hope

Comment: Newbie question, what exactly is 'complete' in this case? on page load is there a single call to loadCompanies? so if that has given a response does that mean observable is completed?

Answer (score 27):

You can do this by using `onCompleted` callback in `subscription`. For example, let's say you show loading bar when user press report button;

```
loadCompanies(): void {
     this._companyService.getCompanies().subscribe(
          response => {
               this.companiesModel = response;
          },
          err => {
               console.log(err);
               //closeLoadingBar();
          },
          () => {
               //do whatever you want
               //closeLoadingBar()
          }
     )
}

generateReport() {
    //showLoadingBar()
    this.loadCompanies();
}
```

If you get error from your http call, `onCompleted` method will not be invoked, only `onError` will be invoked. If it is successful, `onCompleted` method will be called after your `onNext` method.

Here is the documentation for [subscribe](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md). I hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

One more solution:

Actually subscribe function takes three parameters:

onNext 
onError 
onCompleted

```
this._companyService.getCompanies().subscribe(
    (response) => { this.companiesModel = response; },
    (err) => { console.log(err) },
    (finally) => { console.log('finally') }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know about this. But my situation is different.I don't need to trigger my action when observable is complete. When my action is done I need to check if the observable is completed, and if not, to wait until is completed.

Comment: same. Am I forced to set a flag in that callback?  That feels harder than it should be.  Isn't there an observable.isComplete property?

Answer (score 5):

Method

```
finally()
```

> Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence
>   terminates gracefully or exceptionally.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md

Answer (score 4):

In this kind of scenarios it is very useful to use **concatMap** operator to guarantee to execute the next operation only when the previous has done.

```
loadCompanies(): void {
    this._companyService.getCompanies()
    .concatMap(companyList => this.getObservableGenerateReport(companyList))
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.companiesModel = response;
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}


//Create observable to generate the report
getObservableGenerateReport(response: any): Observable<myReportList> {

    return Observable.create(observer => {

      if (generateReport().isSuccessful) {
        observer.next(myReportList);
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        console.log(err, 'Ups, something was wrong!');
        observer.next({});
        observer.complete();
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Something like this I was looking for. Let me try if is working as expected, and I'll mark this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this to debug, the simplest solution is to use the `complete` argument of `tap`:

```
tap(next: null, error: null, complete: () => void)
```

With a source `source$` it would look like this:

```
source$.pipe(
  tap(undefined, undefined, console.log)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to use a shared observable, save the request as a hot observable that way when the report button is clicked it will wait for the request or immediately generate if the request is complete.

```
public companiesModel: Company[];

/** pending request, hot Observable (will emit immediately if complete) */
private companiesRequest: Observable<Company[]>;

constructor(
  private _companyService: CompanyService
) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadCompanies();
}

public generateReport(): void {
  if (this.companiesRequest) {
    // will not make an other network request
    this.companiesRequest.subscribe(
      response => {
        // action using companiesModel.
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}

private loadCompanies(): void {
  this.companiesRequest = this._companyService.getCompanies().pipe(shareReplay());
  this.companiesRequest.subscribe(
    response => {
      this.companiesModel = response;
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/check-if-an-observable-is-completed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Update: You could take it one step further and make the UI async
https://stackblitz.com/edit/check-if-an-observable-is-completed-async-ui?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html