# What happens to a complete observable? What if I subscribe to a completed observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having trouble finding what happens to an Observable when it has completed. I have an observable that must complete before I do other work. To do this, my other functions subscribe that observable, and when it's complete, they do their work.

The question I have is what happens when they subscribe **after** the Observable is complete? From my testing, it appears they get the last value and then it completes (It fires `value` and `complete` callbacks on the `subscribe` method). I'd rather just not subscribe to it to begin with if it has already completed.

**Is there a way to check if an Observable has completed without subscribing?** I was setting it undefined when complete, but it creates an issue if I'm subscribed to observable from another function when that occurs.

I could create a behavior subject `isLoaded` which starts off as False, and goes to true when it's done, but I'm having trouble finding documentation on what a completed observable does when subscribed to and what the best practice is. Thank you!

Edit: This is not asking how to check if an observable is complete. It's asking what happens if an observable completed from a different subscription, how you can check that it had completed. What happens to an observable when it is complete and you look at the Observable object.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032251/angular2-how-can-i-check-if-an-observable-is-completed

Comment: Not a duplicate, completely different question. I'm not asking how to fire the complete method. I'm asking about documentation and what happens when you subscribe after an observable has already completed from a different subscription.

Comment: it depends on what kind of observable it is, right? say, behavior subject or async subject?

Comment: Is there documentation on what happens if you subscribe to an Observable (type Observable, not Behavior Subject) that has already completed. This one: `class Observable<T> implements Subscribable {
  static create: Function
  static if: typeof iif
  static throw: typeof throwError
  constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, observable behaves unicast. Unicast means it is 1:1 relation to subscription, as same as a function. Think most simple function you can think like below:

```
function boo() { //do something }
boo();
```

You need to *call* function to trigger something. Same applies to observable -

```
const someObservable = of(1,2,3);

someObservable.subscribe(...);
```

`someObservable` does *nothing* until you subscribe it. So there is no meaning to check if it's completed or not, as you didn't subscribe to anything. Also there is no meaning to check other subscription's completed or not, as it's 1:1 relation to subscription. You can check subscription's state, but that's different to completion state.

Now there's other type of observable, `multicast` - which is typically represented in implementation of `Subject`. That does emitting regardless of subscription exists, and you could check if it's `closed` to find source itself is closed already. Depends on nature of subject you may observe different behavior, typically you'd get nothing when try to subscribe into completed on for multicasting observables.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not use `endWith` operator, it will simply not emit any value anymore, however it triggers `complete` callback if it's provided. Have not tested it with `finalize` operator but I suppose that it is triggered as well, because observable goes through the same lifecycle each time you subscribe to it.

In case if `endWith` operator is used, then it's value will be emitted on each subsequent subscription once it is completed.

Using **RxJS v.7.1.0**