# Create single Array that contains values of objects sent from parent component

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, emit

Hi I need to create in angular single array that contains values of objects sent from parent component

objects sent from parent console.log('object',o):

```
object {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR130B", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
object {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR130A", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
object {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR25", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
...etc
```

passing it to child component with:

```
this.dataSend.emit(object.designator);
```

reciving data in child:

```
if (this.dataSend) {
    this.dataSend
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
} 

console.log(data):
EPTR130B
EPTR130A
EPTR25
...etc
```

How I supposed to do it to receive array like [ EPTR130B, EPTR130A, EPTR25...]? map? push?

EDIT:
I made some change and passed data as an object to the child with             `this.dataSend.emit({data});`
and receive:

```
{data: Array(63)}
data: Array(63)
0: {type: "ADHOC", designator: "UAV1", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
1: {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR130B", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}}
2: {type: "TRA", designator: "EPTR130A", availabilities: Array(1), info: Array(2), geometry: {…}} ...etc
```

Comment: Might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45039140/38522

Comment: I been trying to do it this way, no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying couple of things, and I don't know if its clean way of operating on arrays and objects but it works:

```
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    let arr: any[]  = [];
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(item) {
        for(let i=0; i<data[item].length; i++){
            arr.push(data[item][i].designator);
        }
        console.log(arr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with `map` of Rxjs and `map` of array.

Try:

```
import { filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'
......
this.dataSend
    .pipe(
       tap((dataArray: any) => console.log(`dataArray before filter: ${dataArray}`)),
       // allow emissions where dataArray is truthy and it has length > 0
       filter((dataArray: any) => !!dataArray && dataArray.length),
       tap((dataArray: any) => console.log(`dataArray after filter: ${dataArray}`)),
       map((dataArray: any) => dataArray.map(data => data.designation)),
     )
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

======================= Edit ==============================
Use the `tap` operator for debugging, you can remove the curtain and see what's going on at that point in time with observables.

Comment: This way I receive  dataArray.map is not a function

Comment: Thank you, however it gives me log:
`dataArray before filter: [object Object]`

Comment: Unfortunately not, `console.log('check',data);` even "check" string is not displayed in console..